# Cannot edit SiteMap in Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, crm-sitemap

The user account I am using for a Dynamics CRM application contains roles for "System Admin" and "System Customizer". But when I try to edit the SiteMap via Settings->Customizations->Customize the System->Client Extensions and selecting SiteMap, I don't see the edit option. Even "My Apps" under Application is not displaying. Please help me point out what Role/Permission is missing.

I am beginner, so any help in this will be very useful.

The version I am using is

Microsoft Dynamics® CRM Online 2016 Update 
(8.1.0.581) (DB 8.1.0.578)

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 2):

In-built sitemap editor is avaiable since version 8.2, so you will have to upgrade your organization first, to have this option. For now you still have to use some external tools like SiteMap Editor from XrmToolbox or simply edit XML manually.

To edit XML manually simply go to customizaitons -> solutions. Create a new solution and under "Client extensions" add "SiteMap". Now export the solution, unzip it and inside "customizations.xml" you will have your sitemap which you can edit. But be careful - editing XML by hand may lead to crashing whole CRM. I would not recommend that on Online - if anything goes wrong, you will not be able to open you CRM and the only way of restoring it would be through Microsoft Support. Simply use the SiteMapEditor from XrmToolbox, it's much better approach.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to use XrmToolbx. If I want to edit the XML directly, where is the XML located?